# AndroidQ When I delete App, system does not automatically remove app‘s storage space

Tags: android-10.0

I'm using Android Emulator with Android Q beta2，Usually when you delete app the system will automatically remove folder 'Android/data/PACKAGE_NAME' and all file in that folder.

However, in Android Q we have four folders:

- 'Android/data/PACKAGE_NAME'
- 'Android/media/PACKAGE_NAME'
- 'Android/obb/PACKAGE_NAME'
- 'Android/sandbox/PACKAGE_NAME'

When you delete app, the OS, only remove folder 'Android/sandbox/PACKAGE_NAME' 
the other three folders are not removed.

This never happens on AndroidP and below.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Is there anything in the other three directories? I doubt that there is anything to "solve", insofar as this is a beta. I don't see [a bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190602%2B%20created%3E%3D2019-03-11%20sandbox), so you might consider filing one with a reproducible test case.

Comment: Yes, the OS does not remove folders and files, causing the app's cache will not be deleted. In short, thank you for your answer, I will create a new issue and ask Google.